# How can we show that $R=S?$

Tags: infinite-product, theta-functions

Let

$$R=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left({q^{2n-1}-1\over q^{2n-1}+1}\right)^2
\left({q^{2n}-1\over q^{2n}+1}\right)^2\tag1$$
and 
$$S=2\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left({q^{2n}+1\over q^{2n}-1}\right)^{2(-1)^{n+1}}
-\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left({q^{n}+1\over q^{n}-1}\right)^{2(-1)^{n+1}}
\tag2$$

**How can we show that $R=S?$**

$(2)$ we can use $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ to factorise but it would turn to be too messy and bulky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equality of $R=S$ is an example of an eta product identity of level $8$. In my collection of [Dedekind Eta Product Identities](http://eta.math.georgetown.edu) I label it as $t_{8,18,60b}$ which can itself be derived from $t_{8,18,60a}$ and $t_{8,12,48}$. In terms of
[Ramanujan theta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_theta_function) it can be written as $\phi(-q)^2 = 2\phi(q^2)^2 - \phi(q)^2$ and this can be derived from $\phi(q)^2=\phi(q^2)^2+4q\psi(q^4)^2$ and $\phi(-q)^2=\phi(q^2)^2-4q\psi(q^4)^2$. In terms of Jacobi theta functions $R=S$ is   as follows: $\theta_4(0,q)^2 = 2\theta_3(0,q^2)^2 - \theta_3(0,q)^2$. They form the basis for parameterization of the Arithmetic-Geometric Mean by squares of theta functions. More precisely, $\;a(q)^2 = b(q)^2 + c(q)^2\;$  where $a(q):=\theta_3(0,q)^2,\;b(q):=\theta_4(0,q)^2,\;c(q):=\theta_2(0,q)^2$ and $\;a(q^2)=(a(q)+b(q))/2,\;b(q^2)=\sqrt{a(q)b(q)},\;c(q^2)=(a(q)-b(q))/2.$

Let us define:

$$Q_0:=\prod_{n>0}1-q^{2n},\;Q_1:=\prod_{n>0}1+q^{2n},
\;Q_2:=\prod_{n>0}1+q^{2n-1},\;Q_3:=\prod_{n>0}1-q^{2n-1}.$$

There are many standard identities between theta functions and infinite products such as $Q_0,Q_1,Q_2,Q_3.$ For example, $1=Q_1Q_2Q_3$ and [DLMF equations 20.4.4 and 20.4.5](http://dlmf.nist.gov/20.4#E4).

Thus, in $R$, $\;Q_0Q_3/(Q_1Q_2)=Q_0Q_3^2=\theta_4(0,q),\;$ and in $S$,
$\;Q_0Q_2/(Q_1Q_3)=Q_0Q_2^2=\theta_3(0,q).$

The $q$-series $R$ is the generating function of OEIS sequence [A104794](http://oeis.org/A104794) and the infinite products in equation (2) come from sequence [A004018](http://oeis.org/A004018) where much information is available.
In all these infinite sums and products, we have to require $|q|<1$ for convergence.

Comment: When you take for granted things like Jacobi triple product you should add a link to a proof

Comment: I recall that name ''Somos'' from somewhere, when I was studying the Somos's quadratic sequence, nice to meet you sir!

Answer (score 1):

These products belong to the theory of theta functions. The expression $R$ is simply $$R=\prod\left(\frac{1-q^{n}}{1+q^{n}}\right) ^{2}=\vartheta_{4}^{2}(q)=\frac{2k'K}{\pi}\tag{1}$$ in terms of Jacobi theta functions and elliptic integral $K$ and complementary modulus $k'$. The first term of $S$ is $$2\prod\left(\frac{1+(q^{2})^{2n-1}}{1-(q^{2})^{2n-1}}\right) ^{2}\left(\frac{1-q^{4n}}{1+q^{4n}} \right)^{2}=2\vartheta_{3}^{2}(q^{2})=\frac{4L}{\pi}\tag{2}$$ where $L$ is Elliptic integral corresponding to modulus $l=(1-k')/(1+k')$ based on nome $q^{2}$. Similarly the second term in $S$ is $$\prod\left(\frac{1+q^{2n-1}}{1-q^{2n-1}}\right) ^{2}\left(\frac{1-q^{2n}}{1+q^{2n}}\right)^{2}=\vartheta_{3}^{2}(q)=\frac{2K}{\pi}\tag{3}$$ The equality $R=S$ is equivalent to $$\vartheta_{3}^{2}(q)+\vartheta_{4}^{2}(q)=2\vartheta_{3}^{2}(q^{2})\tag{4}$$ and this identity is famous. If we observe the series representation of $\vartheta_{3}(q)$ as $$\vartheta_{3}(q)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}q^{n^{2}}$$ then it is easy to see that $$\vartheta_{3}^{2}(q)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r_{2}(n)q^{n}\tag{5}$$ where $r_{2}(n)$ is the number of ways in which $n$ can be expressed as sum of two squares (sign as well as order of summands being counted). And we have $$\vartheta_{4}^{2}(q)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}r_{2}(n)q^{n}$$ and hence $$\vartheta_{3}^{2}(q)+\vartheta_{4}^{2}(q)=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r_{2}(2n)q^{2n}$$ Next we note a simple fact from elementary number theory that if $n$ can be expressed as a sum of two squares then $2n$ can also be represented in that manner and vice versa (use the equation $2(a^{2}+b^{2})=(a-b)^{2}+(a+b)^{2}$). This gives us $r_{2}(2n)=r_{2}(n)$ and hence the last equation can be written as $$\vartheta_{3}^{2}(q)+\vartheta_{4}^{2}(q)=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r_{2}(n)q^{2n}=2\vartheta_{3}^{2}(q^{2})$$ which proves $(4)$. The part which we have not shown here is the equivalence of series and product representations of various theta functions and this is based on [Jacobi's Triple Product Identity](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/02/elliptic-functions-theta-functions-contd.html) $$\sum_{n=-\infty} ^{\infty} z^{n} q^{n^{2}}=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-q^{2n})(1+q^{2n-1}z)(1+q^{2n-1}z^{-1})\tag{6}$$ There is something which must be said for the elliptic integrals involved in these identities. The identity $(4)$ in terms of elliptic integrals is $$(1+k')K=2L$$ which follows from [Landen transformation](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/01/elliptic-functions-landens-transformation.html) of elliptic integrals. The above proof as well as the link between elliptic integrals and theta functions is explored [here](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2010/10/the-magic-of-theta-functions.html) and [here](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2010/10/the-magic-of-theta-functions-contd.html).