# Prove $\prod_{n \in \Bbb{N} } \left(\frac{1-q^n}{1+q^n}\right)^{(-1)^n} = \sum_{n \in \Bbb{Z}} q^{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, infinite-product

Let $q$ be a complex number with $|q| < 1$, prove that
$$
\prod_{n \in \Bbb{N} } \left(\dfrac{1-q^n}{1+q^n}\right)^{(-1)^n} = \sum_{n \in \Bbb{Z}} q^{n^2}
$$

Not sure if this helps but the LHS can also be written as

$$
\prod_{n\in \Bbb{N}\\\text{n odd}}(1+q^n)(1+q^n+q^{2n}+\cdots)\prod_{n \in \Bbb{N} \\\text{n even}} (1-q^n)(1-q^n+q^{2n}-\cdots)
$$

I've tried [the method here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2861580/518781) and [the method here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2477308/518781), but they both give me nightmares. Is there any good idea?

Comment: Have you tried the Jacobi triple product

Comment: You may find information in this similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2425852)

Comment: Thx, they look useful. I'll try

Comment: For $|q|\ge1$ the equality does not make sense, does it?

Comment: Hmm I think you are right. Edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that
$$\begin{align}\prod_{n \in \Bbb{N} } \left(\dfrac{1-q^n}{1+q^n}\right)^{(-1)^n}&=
\prod_{n \in \Bbb{N} } \left(\dfrac{1-q^{2n}}{1+q^{2n}}\right)\left(\dfrac{1+q^{2n-1}}{1-q^{2n-1}}\right)\\
&=\prod_{n \in \Bbb{N} } \dfrac{1+q^n}{1+q^{2n}}\dfrac{1-q^{n}}{1-q^{2n-1}}(1+q^{2n-1})\\
&=\prod_{n \in \Bbb{N} } \dfrac{1+q^n}{1+q^{2n}}\prod_{n \in \Bbb{N} }\dfrac{1-q^{n}}{1-q^{2n-1}}\prod_{n \in \Bbb{N} }(1+q^{2n-1})\\
&=\prod_{n \in \Bbb{N} }(1+q^{2n-1})\prod_{n \in \Bbb{N} }(1-q^{2n})\prod_{n \in \Bbb{N} }(1+q^{2n-1})\\
&=
\prod_{n \in \Bbb{N} }(1-q^{2n})(1+q^{2n-1})^2\\
&=\sum_{n \in \Bbb{Z}} q^{n^2}
\end{align}$$
where at the last step we applied the [Jacobi triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product) for $x=q$ and $y=1$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you also explain the next-to-last step?

Comment: @user We have that
$$\prod_{n \in \Bbb{N} } \dfrac{1+q^n}{1+q^{2n}}=\dfrac{\prod_{n \in \Bbb{N} }(1+q^n)}{\prod_{n \in \Bbb{N} }(1+q^{2n})}=\dfrac{\prod_{n \in \Bbb{N} }(1+q^{2n})\prod_{n \in \Bbb{N} }(1+q^{2n-1})}{\prod_{n \in \Bbb{N} }(1+q^{2n})}=\prod_{n \in \Bbb{N} }(1+q^{2n-1})$$
Similarly we handel $\prod_{n \in \Bbb{N} } \dfrac{1-q^n}{1-q^{2n-1}}$.

Comment: Thank you for adding this explanation!